# cannot start cassandra on Mac M1

Tags: cassandra, apple-m1

```
Arch: Apple M1
OS: Mac 13.0.1
Java: 17
Cassandra: 4.1
```

I tried two way to install Cassandra on Mac:

1. homebrew
2. download the apache-cassandra-4.1.0-bin.tar.gz from official website

When I try to run cassandra, I got the following error:

```
dyld[29837]: terminating because inserted dylib '/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.dylib' could not be loaded: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need '')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need '')), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jemalloc/5.3.0/lib/libjemalloc.2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need '')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jemalloc/5.3.0/lib/libjemalloc.2.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jemalloc/5.3.0/lib/libjemalloc.2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need ''))
dyld[29837]: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need '')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need '')), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jemalloc/5.3.0/lib/libjemalloc.2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need '')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jemalloc/5.3.0/lib/libjemalloc.2.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jemalloc/5.3.0/lib/libjemalloc.2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need ''))
Error parsing arguments! Unknown argument ""
```

Supprisingly, cqlsh works. It can be used to connect to other cassandra server.

It seems libjemalloc.dylib is not correct. It is confusing to see `(have 'arm64', need '')`
What should I do?

Comment: Does Cassandra support ARM-based processors?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra 4.1 will run on a maximum JDK version of 11.  Java 17 will not work; you’ll need to downgrade.

Comment: It seems not a JDK version problem, I tried to run with JDK 11, and the same error occurred. I guess it is related to libjemalloc on Mac.